# Any way to mark specific files on Eclipse's Package Explorer? A bit like bookmarking but with a visual cue?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering if there's a way to mark a specific file in Eclipse's Package Explorer (to either underline it, or paint it in another color, whatever).

I'm currently exploring some unknown code and it'd be nice if I could mark files as I see they're relevant for my endeavors (possibly, with different colors or such). That way I could quickly visually get what are the most relevant files in the package explorer. As files / folders are in different folders, that would mean loads of help.

Eclipse's bookmarks would work wonderfully were it not for the fact it doesn't bring about any visual cue in the package explorer, thus not allowing me to see the rich file/folder hierarchy their organization provides.

I'm ok with solutions envolving 3rd-party plugins, if in any way necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mylyn plugin and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>.